# Sharing array memoryfile C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, c++14

i trying share a array via memoryfile c++ to c# based on this example:[stream data from c++ to c# over shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37572938/stream-data-from-c-to-c-sharp-over-shared-memory).
work fine, but i just can get until position 3 from array, another position come 0.

C++ that creat MemoryFile

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Pair {
    int length;
    int data[10];
};

struct Pair* p;
HANDLE handle;

int dataSend[10]{ 500,33,44,66,2,55,98,7,52,36 };

bool startShare()
{
    try
    {
        handle = CreateFileMappingW(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, sizeof(Pair), L"DataSend");
        p = (struct Pair*) MapViewOfFile(handle, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, sizeof(Pair));
        return true;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return false;
    }

}


int main()
{

    if (startShare() == true)
    {
        printf("Memory Create");
        while (true)
        {
            if (p != 0) {


                for (int h = 0; h < 10; h++)
                {
                     p->data[h] = dataSend[h];
                     printf("\n number %d", dataSend[h]);
                }

            }


            else
                puts("create shared memory error");
        }
    }
    if (handle != NULL)
        CloseHandle(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

my C# Read

```
public static int[] data = new int[10];
public static MemoryMappedFile mmf;
public static MemoryMappedViewStream mmfvs;

static public bool MemOpen()
{
    try
    {
        mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("DataSend");
        mmfvs = mmf.CreateViewStream();
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }

}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (MemOpen())
        {

            byte[] blen = new byte[4];
            mmfvs.Read(blen, 0, 4);

            byte[] bPosition = new byte[280];
            mmfvs.Read(bPosition, 0, 280);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(bPosition, 0, data, 0, bPosition.Length);

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(data[i]);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

work fine, but i just can get until position 3 from array, another position come 0.

**Update, code work fine now**
Just a detail,i return a array  hex value example:52A7E600
but in my code c# get bit numbers like: 10300071984, how i cant convert in side c# to get same format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to convert long value  to hex in c# you could use:

```
        long intValue = 10300071984;
        // Convert long value 10300071984 -> 265EEA030 as a hex in a string variable
        string hexValue = intValue.ToString("X");
```